# Converting text to format string

Tags: python

Is there some python way to convert a text (from a file for example) into a format string?
I mean for a text file:

```
this is a {format}
string.
```

Load it in python and have it become like the triple quotes format string:

```
var = """this is a {format}
string."""
```

I know how to just read the file and replace the curly braces, but I was wondering if there is already something that does this.

Thanks

Edit:
This is the code I've tried:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as rs:
    lines = rs.readlines()
text = ','.join(lines)
print(text)
text.format(format='something_else')
print(text)
```

It just prints the text file.
I'm looking to know if there is a more pythonic way then me having to write a class that does this.
Thanks

Comment: There is no difference between those. Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: ofcourse. It doesn't work and it just loads it as plain text

Comment: Strings are plain text too. Did you try `with open('file.txt') as f: print(f.read().format(format='hello'))`?

Comment: `str.format()` doesn't operate in-place.

Comment: THis works thanks! I see what I missed there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`variable.format()` returns the formatted text and does not change the content of `variable`. Try

```
print(text.format(format="bla"))
```

or

```
text = text.format(format="bla")
```